# Getting error when adding a middleware to the route in Slim

Tags: php, slim, middleware

I wrote this code in Slim and it works fine but when I add the middleware I get the following error!!! Can not figure out what is happening, could any one please help me.

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 3 passed to fileFilter() must be callable, array given FILENAME in line 90
```

This middleware filters unsupported file types

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Api\ErrorList as ErrorList;

function fileFilter(Request $request, Response $response, callable $next){
        $allowedFiles = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf'];
        $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
        $flattened =array_flatten($files);

        foreach ($flattened as $key=> $newFile){
            $newFileType = $newFile->getClientMediaType();

            if(!in_array($newFileType, $allowedFiles)) {
                return ResponseHelper::createfailureResponse($response, HTTPStatusCodes::BAD_REQUEST, ErrorList::UNSUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE);
            }

        }
        return $next($request, $response); // line 90
    }
```

And here I add the middleware to my route.

```
 $app->group('/test/api/v1', function () {
        // other routes here
        $this->post('/resume/edit','fileFilter', ResumeController::class. ':edit')->setName('Resume.edit');


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove 'fileFilter' from

```
$this->post('/resume/edit', ...
```

and change it to something like

```
$this->post(...)->add((Request $request, Response $response, callable $next){
    $allowedFiles = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf'];
    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $flattened =array_flatten($files);

    foreach ($flattened as $key=> $newFile){
        $newFileType = $newFile->getClientMediaType();

        if(!in_array($newFileType, $allowedFiles)) {
            return ResponseHelper::createfailureResponse($response, HTTPStatusCodes::BAD_REQUEST, ErrorList::UNSUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE);
        }

    }
    return $next($request, $response); // line 90
});
```

or as invokable class

```
class MyMiddleware
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, callable $next){
        $allowedFiles = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf'];
        $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
        $flattened =array_flatten($files);

        foreach ($flattened as $key=> $newFile){
            $newFileType = $newFile->getClientMediaType();

            if(!in_array($newFileType, $allowedFiles)) {
                return ResponseHelper::createfailureResponse($response, HTTPStatusCodes::BAD_REQUEST, ErrorList::UNSUPPORTED_FILE_TYPE);
           }

        }
        return $next($request, $response); // line 90
    }
}
```

and in route

```
$this->post(...)->add(MyMiddleware::class);
```

[Slim Middleware](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/middleware.html)